# Meteor Dynamically Create Objects and refer to them? // Is there a simple way to do this

Tags: javascript, meteor, expandable

So, im really new to both JavaScript and Meteor, so I only know a handful of things.

Learning both, JavaScript and Meteor I set myself the challenge to make a 3 by 3 field of  with individual counters in them, that count, if you click the cell.

I reached my first goal: http://9fields.meteor.com/

The second goal I set for myself was to try to make it easily expandable. Say, i want to make the same field but 7x7.

Every cell has its own template.

```
<template name="zelle1">                      
  <td class="box">                          
    <p class="textinbox">{{counter}}</p>  
  </td>                                     
</template>
```

Every cell has its own counter and every cell has one event handler and one helper to register a click

```
Template.zelle1.helpers({
counter: function () {
  return Session.get("counter1");
}

});

Template.zelle1.events({
"click td": function() {
  return Session.set("counter1", Session.get("counter1")+1);
}
});
```

I then pasted the code 8 more times and replaced the numbers.

The only thing that i feel reaches my criteria for the second goal is the way i create the table.

```
<table>                                         
    {{#each zellen}}                            
        {{#if this.newrow}}                     
            <tr></tr>                           
            {{> UI.dynamic template=this.name}} 
        {{else}}                                
            {{> UI.dynamic template=this.name}} 
        {{/if}}                                 
    {{/each}}                                   
</table>
```

in combination with this Array (array is the right word?)

```
Template.body.zellen = [
{name: "zelle1", newrow: false},
{name: "zelle2", newrow: false},
{name: "zelle3", newrow: false},
{name: "zelle4", newrow: true},
{name: "zelle5", newrow: false},
{name: "zelle6", newrow: false},
{name: "zelle7", newrow: true},
{name: "zelle8", newrow: false},
{name: "zelle9", newrow: false},
];
```

My question: Do i have to make 9 Templates and 9 helpers and 9 events for those 9 fields? Meaning that if i want to make a 7x7 field i need to paste the code 49 times? Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Already Thank you for reading through this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's propose a third way to approach the problem :)
You can always use something like the following to get multiple Session variables filled:

```
var fieldSize = 9;
for (i = 1; i <= fieldSize; i++) { 
    Session.set("counter" + i, i); // sets 9 Session variables
}
```

Or perhaps use an array inside the `Session`. It can even be an array of objects:

```
var fieldSize = 9;
var fields = [];
for (i = 1; i <= fieldSize; i++) {
    fields.push({name: i, count: i});
}
Session.set("fields", fields);
```

This is basically the same approach as using `ReactiveVar`, only that you are using a global variable (`Session`) instead of a scoped one. You entire application will be able to access the things you store within `Session`.

Also, you should perhaps not use a template bound to each field, but iterate using `{{#each}}`

```
<template name="fields">                      
  {{#each withIndex fields}}
     {{> zelle}}
  {{/each}}                                    
</template>
```

The trouble here is that you have no control over which cell you are rendering currently, so you need to add an index to each of the `{{#each}}` runs. This is why I suggest a new global helper `withIndex`:

```
Template.registerHelper('withIndex', function (list) {
var withIndex = _.map(list, function (v, i) {
    v.index = i;
    return v;
});
return withIndex;
});
```

You can use the new `index` just like any other field from the array. You will need it to determine which number was clicked and where to increase the counter. I've used the `td`'s `id` value to store the index of which cell was clicked.

```
<template name="zelle">                      
  <td class="box" id="zelle-{{index}}">                          
    <p class="textinbox">{{name}} with a count of {{count}}</p>  
  </td>                                     
</template>  

Template.fields.helpers({
    fields: function () {
        return Session.get("fields");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you start reading you should get familiar with Meteor collections because this is the best way to do your example, and how "this" works inside of #each loop

You can create one template and pass data to this

```
<template name="zelle">                      
  <td class="box">                          
    <p class="textinbox">{{name}}</p>  
  </td>                                     
</template>
```

And main template can look something like this

```
<table>
  {{#each zellen}}
   <tr>
   {{#each zellen}}
     {{>zelle}}
   {{/each}}
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```

This first `#each` can have any other helper, but if you want to have square you need same count of loops through `<td>` and `<tr>`

I would rather make a collection to hold your data

On client side you can make something like this:

```
yourCollection= new Meteor.Collection('yourCollection');

Meteor.startup(function(){
   If(yourCollection.find().count()==0){
   yourCollection.insert({name:1});
   yourCollection.insert({name:2});
   etc...
}
});
```

And event can look like this:

```
"click td": function() {
  yourCollection.update({_id:this._id},{$inc:{name:1}});
}
```

Since you now have a collection zellen helper should look like

```
zellen: function(){
  return yourCollection.find();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer Sindis gave looks correct, assuming you want to use a collection to manage the reactivity. In most cases you do, but not always. I'll propose an alternative solution which uses [scoped reactivity](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) where each template keeps track of it's own state without the need for global session variables. Warning - this is a somewhat advanced topic. Here's a working solution:

### app.html

```
<body>
  <table>
    {{#each zellen}}
      {{#if newrow}}
        <tr></tr>
      {{/if}}
      {{> zelle}}
    {{/each}}
  </table>
</body>

<template name="zelle">
  <td class="box">
    <p class="textinbox">{{counter}}</p>
  </td>
</template>
```

### app.js

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
    zellen: function() {
      var rows = 3;
      var columns = 4;

      // dynamically build the zellen
      var zellen = _.times(rows * columns, function(i) {
        var newrow = false;
        if ((i % columns) === 0)
          newrow = true;

        return {count: i + 1, newrow: newrow}
      });

      return zellen;
    }
  });

  Template.zelle.created = function() {
    this.counter = new ReactiveVar;
    this.counter.set(this.data.count);
  };

  Template.zelle.helpers({
    counter: function () {
      return Template.instance().counter.get();
    }
  });

  Template.zelle.events({
    click: function(e, template) {
      var count = template.counter.get();
      template.counter.set(count + 1);
    }
  });
}
```

Note you will need to run `meteor add reactive-var` for this to work.